# Combining two SQL Select Statements

Tags: sql

I have basic SQL knowledge and trying to write and SQL statement for the following question:

Q: List all students that have the Measles immunity[enter image description here][1], but a religious exemption for Varicella.

What I have:
**Religious Exemption**

```
SELECT *
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN Waiver ON Person.personID = Waiver.personID
INNER JOIN WavierDisease On Waiver.waiverID = WaiverDisease.waiverID
INNER JOIN Disease ON WaiverDisease.diseaseID = Disease.diseaseID
WHERE Disease.diseaseName = ‘Chickenpox’
AND Waiver.exemptCode = ‘Religious’);
```

**People With Measles Vaccine**

```
SELECT *
FROM Immunity I
INNER JOIN Disease ON I.diseaseID = Disease.diseaseID
WHERE Disease.diseaseName = 'Measles';
```

I am not sure how to combine the two to get a single result.

Attached is the logical model of the db.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQGqC.png

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code above, you could just extend the JOIN and WHERE condition

```
SELECT DISTINCT(P.personID)
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN Waiver ON Person.personID = Waiver.personID
INNER JOIN WavierDisease On Waiver.waiverID = WaiverDisease.waiverID
INNER JOIN Disease ON WaiverDisease.diseaseID = Disease.diseaseID
INNER JOIN Immunity ON Person.personID = Immunity.personID -- add this
WHERE
Disease.diseaseName = ‘Chickenpox’
AND Waiver.exemptCode = ‘Religious’
AND Immunity.diseaseId IN ( -- add this
   SELECT diseaseId FROM Disease WHERE Disease.diseaseName = 'Measles'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To effectively answer the question,

> Q: List all students that have the Measles immunity, but a religious exemption for Varicella.

you need to query for two conditions: 1) measles immunity AND 2) religious exemption for varicella (or chicken pox).

Therefore, consider adding `Immunity` as another `JOIN` and second join to `Disease` table:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Waiver w                        --- WAIVER CHECK
    ON  w.personID AND p.personID
    AND w.exemptCode = 'Religious'
INNER JOIN WavierDisease wd  
    ON wd.waiverID = w.waiverID
INNER JOIN Disease d1
    ON  d1.diseaseID = wd.diseaseID
    AND d1.diseaseName = 'Chickenpox'

INNER JOIN Immunity i                      --- IMMUNITY CHECK
   ON i.personID AND p.personID
INNER JOIN Disease d2
   ON  d2.diseaseID = i.diseaseID
   AND d2.diseaseName = 'Measles'
```

Answer (score 0):

> List all students that have ...

1. "List all students" means select from the students table. (Which is your table "person" I guess? Or is it only certain persons from that table maybe?)
2. "that have ..." translates to `WHERE ...`. And as the information is in other tables you need `EXISTS` or `IN`.

If I understand your data model correctly, this gets us:

```
select *
from person
where personid in 
(
  select personid
  from immunity
  where diseaseid = (select diseaseid from disease where diseaseName = 'Measles')
)
and personid in
(
  select personid
  from waiver
  where exemptCode = 'Religious'
  and waiverid in 
  (
    select waiverid
    from waiverdisease 
    where diseaseid = (select diseaseid from disease where diseaseName = 'Chickenpox')
  )
);
```

I consider this readable. And because of using `IN` rather than joins, we have made sure not to get any duplicates with our lookups.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `union`

```
SELECT *
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN Waiver ON Person.personID = Waiver.personID
INNER JOIN WavierDisease On Waiver.waiverID = WaiverDisease.waiverID
INNER JOIN Disease ON WaiverDisease.diseaseID = Disease.diseaseID
WHERE Disease.diseaseName = ‘Chickenpox’
AND Waiver.exemptCode = ‘Religious’
union
SELECT *
FROM Immunity I
INNER JOIN Disease ON I.diseaseID = Disease.diseaseID
WHERE Disease.diseaseName = 'Measles';
```

Comment: I **strongly** doubt that `Person p` and `Immunity I` tables will have the same columns in order for this to work .......

Comment: The person who asked the question said they have basic knowledge of SQL and you're giving them an answer where you do a UNION between two different results. The person is going to get the wrong idea and get confused. I'm now sure you understood what the person who posted the question is looking for, none of us have because it lacks an example.

Comment: With some modified code, I got it to work with union.  Thank you.

Comment: `UNION` gives you all persons that have the waiver **or** the immunity. You need `INTERSECT` instead to get all persons that have the waiver **and** the immunity.

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work.  Thanks for the quick help.

```
SELECT Immunity.personID
FROM Immunity
INNER JOIN Disease ON Immunity.diseaseID = Disease.diseaseID
WHERE Disease.diseaseName = 'Measles'
UNION
SELECT Person.personID
FROM Person
INNER JOIN Waiver ON Person.personID = Waiver.personID
INNER JOIN WaiverDisease On Waiver.waiverID = WaiverDisease.waiverID
INNER JOIN Disease ON WaiverDisease.disease = Disease.diseaseID
WHERE Disease.diseaseName = 'Chickenpox'
AND Waiver.exemptTypeCode = 'Religious';
```

Comment: This query does not answer the question you post. `UNION` queries are elaborate `OR` (+ DISTINCT) not `AND` conditions.

Comment: Parfait is right. You'd want `INTERSECT` instead, if your DBMS supports this. The table person is not needed in the lower query by the way.